# Show that $M(t)=(W(t)-t)e^{-W(t)-t/2}$ is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Define $$M(t)=(W(t)-t)exp(-W(t)-\frac{1}{2}t)$$ where $W(t)$ is Brownian motion. I want to show that this is a martingale. I have tried with Ito formula and end up with only a $dW_t$ term. However I failed to proof that the Integrand of $dW_t$ term is square integrable. Furthermore I want to ask if it is possible to proof with direct definition of martingale, I.e. Without using Itos formula.

**Edit:** Sorry for the late reply, for the completeness I will finish the question to Did's Suggestion.

I could use Ito's Lemma to prove the following identity:
$$dM(t)=(t-W(t)+1)exp(-W(t)-\frac{1}{2}t)dW(t)$$. So if I can prove that the factor is square integrable then we are done.
Define a stochastic exponential$$L(T)=exp(-2W(T)-T)$$, one can use the Girsanov theorem to deduce(Novikov condition is fulfilled since we have a deterministic function):
$$E[(t-W(t)+1)^2*L(t)]=E^{\Bbb{Q}}[(t-W(t)+1)^2]=E^{\Bbb{Q}}[(t-(W(t)+2t)+2t+1)^2]=E^{\Bbb{Q}}[(t-\tilde W(t)+2t+1)^2]<\infty$$, where $\tilde W(t)$ is a $\Bbb Q$ brownian motion. As the integrand is square integrable one can show easily that $\int _0^T E[((t-W(t)+1)exp(-W(t)-\frac{1}{2}t))^2]dt<\infty$, which ensures that the stochastic integral is a martingale.

Comment: Which factor of $dW_t$ did you fall on? Unless you provide this piece of information, how do you expect to get an answer to this part of your question?